# How to delete armature layer?

Tags: armature

How can I delete/clear only one armature layer?

[image]

I've tried to use "Remove from keying set" function, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: Select all its bones and delete them? Or move them to another layer with M if you don't want to delete them

Comment: @moonboots oh, yeah. Seems like it was too obvious for me. It's an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all its bones and delete them. Or move them to another layer with <kbd>M</kbd> if you don't want to delete them.